# Properties File Java

Tags: java, properties

I want to use a pre-configured properties `File`, load it, and after that, add  a line under the already present line from the default `config.properties`.

I have a `read()` function that will read/load my default `Properties` file and I have a `write()` function that will add `String key = "hey"; String value = "ho";`

But when I launch `read()` and `write()` and when i look in the new `config.properties` I only see

```
hey=ho
```

In my default config.properties i got

```
 ha=hi 

 hu=hu
```

But I want in my new config :

```
ha=hi  

hu=hu

hey=ho
```

My code:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
public static PropertiesIParse instance;

public PropertiesIParse() {
    instance = this;
}

public PropertiesIParse getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public Properties getProp() {
    return prop;
}

public void read() {

    InputStream input = null;

    try {
        String filename = "/config.properties";
        input = PropertiesIParse.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
        if (input == null) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find " + filename);
            return;
        }

        getProp().load(input);
        Enumeration<?> e = getProp().propertyNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) e.nextElement();
            String value = getProp().getProperty(key);
            System.out.println("KeyKey : " + key + ", Value : " + value);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void write() {

    String filename = "config.properties";
    FileOutputStream out;
    //prop = new Properties();

    String key = "hey";
    String value = "ho";

    try {

        out = new FileOutputStream(filename, true);
        getProp().setProperty(key, value);
        getProp().store(out, "--type--"); // <---- variable pour dire YYYY MM DD etc.
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException i) {
        System.out.println("Probleme avec l'écriture dans le fichier Property." + i.getMessage());
        i.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So, in my Main method:

```
new PropertiesIParse().getInstance().read();
new PropertiesIParse().getInstance().write();
```

## EDIT

i change what you say but i got the same thing ... a new config.properties with only my prop.store(key,value) in it

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
static PropertiesIParse instance;

private PropertiesIParse() {
    instance = this;
}

public static PropertiesIParse getInstance() {
      if (instance== null) {
            instance = new PropertiesIParse();
        }
        return instance;
}

public void read() {

    InputStream input = null;
    Properties prop = new Properties();

    try {
        String filename = "config.properties";
        input = PropertiesIParse.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);

        if (input == null) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find " + filename);
            return;
        }
        prop.load(input);
        Enumeration<?> e = prop.propertyNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) e.nextElement();
            String value =prop.getProperty(key);
            System.out.println("Key : " + key + ", Value : " + value);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void write(String key, String value) {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String filename = "./config.properties";
    String comment="";
    FileOutputStream out;

    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(filename, true);
        prop.setProperty(key, value);
        prop.store(out, "-"+key+"-"+comment); 
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException i) {
        System.out.println("Probleme avec l'écriture dans le fichier Property." + i.getMessage());
        i.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My Main

```
PropertiesIParse.getInstance().read();
PropertiesIParse.getInstance().write(new String("ok"),new String("iiiii"));
```

And i only got ok=iiiii in it ... i surely miss something there, thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Your singleton is broken as you use a public constructor. Each time you call -

```
new PropertiesIParse()
```

there a new instance of Properties will be created which will be empty.
Make the constructor private and change the `getInstance()` as follows

```
public PropertiesIParse getInstance() {
    if (instance== null) {
        instance = new PropertiesIParse();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Then use it without using `new`:

```
PropertiesIParse.getInstance().read();
PropertiesIParse.getInstance().write();
```

Comment: Or start with a non-lazy singleton. Much less hassle.

Comment: In your edit you also added `Properties prop = new Properties();` in your methods. So the prop will always be empty bevor you add the new values. Remove those lines and it should work.

Comment: i remove those two lines in my methods but i still only get my last entry in my new config.properties

Comment: Are you sure you removed it also from your read()-method? I tried your code (removed the mentioned lines) and it works fine. Do you have other code around that is not shown here that could influence the behaviour?

Comment: i check it but i think i follow exactly your order

Comment: Ho man it worked, i was missing something surely, i will read my code again and try to understand better this process

Thanks all !